# Flutter Linux Build Exception Using media_kit_video package

Tags: linux, flutter, dart

I am getting this error when trying to build on linux using flutter. I installed flutter using snapd.

```
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/media_kit_video/linux/CMakeLists.txt:16 (add_library):
  Target "media_kit_video_plugin" links to target "PkgConfig::mpv" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/media_kit_native_event_loop/src/CMakeLists.txt:52 (add_library):
  Target "media_kit_native_event_loop" links to target "PkgConfig::mpv" but
  the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
Building Linux application...                                           
Unable to generate build files
```

I tried to clear the pub-cache and reimport all the packages using pub-get but still getting the same error.

These are the packages I am using:

```
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
media_kit: ^1.1.10
media_kit_video: ^1.2.4
media_kit_libs_video: ^1.0.4
provider: ^6.0.5
signalr_core: ^1.1.1
intl: ^0.18.1
path_provider: ^2.1.1
cron: ^0.5.1
ntp: ^2.0.0
http: ^0.13.6
```

Flutter doctor is all okay

Answer (score 0):

did you try this command?

sudo apt install libmpv-dev mpv

Comment: and if you install flutter by snapd
some function can not be working

thus you should install flutter manually

Comment: Answer should've been a comment.

Comment: No, I didn't try that command, the project was to be delivered within a few days so, to play the video, I used another package which worked for all platform similar to this but was like a wrapper to the official video player by flutter team. Package:  [**_FVP package_**](https://pub.dev/packages/fvp).
Also not related but there was another issue with the device and OS I was using, the device was a custom hardware and the linux was a custom distro of debian 10. The architecture was x64 but flutter was giving error as if it was x32.